# Google Maps: find information about roads according to GPS data

Tags: google-maps

I'd like to know if it is possible, using Google Maps, to get informations about roads, such as:

- Name of the road;
- If it's a highway or not;
- Length of the road;
- Altitude of the road, and even better: ranges of altitudes (example : from 15ft to 150ft)
- Traffic data, like traffic lights, traffic usage, etc.

The input data I have are a bunch of GPS data (longitudes and latitude coordinates).

So basically, I'd like to find a way to do this : 
[image]

I can imagine there isn't a software that does this, but maybe if you can give me some clues on how to do such a thing.

Comment: Here (Nokia) API can give you all that information you will need an api key (90 days trial) before you have to subscribe example Road Element (length) https://developer.here.com/mobile-sdks/documentation/android-starter/topics_api_nlp/com-here-android-mpa-common-roadelement.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if you can do what you're asking for with Google Maps, but you could certainly do so with OpenStreetMap (OSM). The dataset is crowdsourced, and thus will be "unofficial," but should have information on:

- Names of roads/highways
- Highway (you can use the key=highway tag)

As well as coupling with other layers such as a digital elevation model to extra elevations and geometry functions to pull lengths of the roads. You could use basic desktop GIS software such as QGIS to do so.

I am not sure about information on traffic data but others could chime in here if they know of such datasets. One possibility for deriving your own traffic estimates would be to estimate it or model it as a function of a population layer. This might get a bit complex and thus if there are other datasets you could plug into, that might be a better option.

Depending on how big of an area you are looking at, the tasks you describe could get complex.

Comment: Thank you very much for this answer ! I'll try it and let you know if I come up with some results.

Comment: Thanks -- if you find it was useful, feel free to mark my response as an answer :)